# How to print a string which was scanned by scanf ("%*[^\n]", str);

Tags: c

I used this lines to scan a string with space

```
scanf ("%*[^\n]", first_line);
 printf("%s\n",first_line);
```

But it doesnt work!!! What to do?

Comment: `%*`: I think that ignores the field, so `first_line` isn't set by `scanf`

Comment: Why not use `fgets`? It is more safe than `scanf`.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the error you get?

Comment: If you're really using `C++` (you tagged this as `C++`), why use `scanf` when there are far easier ways to read a string with a space?

Comment: `scanf ("%*[^\n]", first_line);` should have raised a compiler warning.  Save time and enable all warnings.

Comment: Note: C library defines a _line_ as "each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character." .  `scanf ("%*[^\n]", first_line);` might scan most of a line, but not a final `'\n`'.

Comment: Tip: Avoid down-votes.  Rather than "But it doesnt work!!!" post input used, output seen and expected output.

Comment: What do you mean with _It doesn't work_? What output did you expect and what output did you get?  How is `first_line` declared?  the `%*[^\n]` format n my opinion lacks some format characters and it's not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` in `scanf ("%*[^\n]", first_line);` tells `scanf` to scan but not store the scanned string.

In your case, you only have one argument, which is not set because of this.

Note that `-Wall` (or `-Wformat-extra-args`) issues a warning on "recent" `gcc` compilers:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:6:8: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
 scanf ("%*[^\n]", first_line);
        ^~~~~~~~~
```

That works fine:

```
 scanf ("%[^\n]", first_line);
 printf("%s\n",first_line);
```

and you can even limit the size to read (making `scanf` safer) like this:

```
char first_line[10] = {0};
scanf ("%9[^\n]", first_line);
```

so even if user enters more than 9 characters, you don't overflow your buffer

Note however that if no characters are present on the line before the `\n`, `scanf()` will fail to match the `%[^\n]` conversion specification and return `0` without consuming any byte from standard input.  For this reason, it is much more advisable to use `fgets()` for your purpose:

```
char line[100];

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
    /* a line was read from standard input */
    /* you can strip the newline character with this simple one liner */
    line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie good job. I still have a lot to learn about those scanf subtleties. C isn't the easiest language to deal with text files.

Answer (score 2):

```
 scanf ("%*[^\n]", first_line);
```

This code will discard all the characters until `\n` is encountered. So you are not storing any value in your `first_line` variable.

Don't use `scanf` for reading character array or strings. Instead you can use `fgets`.

[Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

```
char first_line[80];
while(fgets(first_line, 80, stdin)) {
    printf("%s",first_line);
}
```

Where 80 is size of your `first_line` character array.

Comment: Dear downvoter I would really appreciate if you could provide a reason for the downvote. This way I can improve my post and learn something new. Thanks!

Comment: not the downvoter, but you didn't explain why the OP code didn't work, and just proposed another way to do it, discouraging him/her to use `scanf`, which is still useful when used properly. It gives the impression of an off-topic answer. Then, (this is probably minor) `fgets` isn't strictly equivalent since it consumes the \n

Comment: Thanks for the input @Jean-FrançoisFabre.

Comment: at least you improved your post. +1